# merging two data sets on the basis of two columns

Tags: regex, r

There are n files. In each file there are multiple columns and i have to select only first two. I have to merge these n files on the basis of those two columns with an additional column. The value will be like a string. The length of the string depends on number of files. For instance, say there are 4 files,
File1:

```
cat  dog 
lion ele
mice hello
new  lion
ele  that
```

File2:

```
 cat lion
 mice hello
 cub  pet
 old  lion
```

File3:

```
new    lion
cub    pet
cat    dog
hello  cat
```

File4:

```
ele  that
hello cat
new   old
```

I want to generate a new file,

```
cat    dog     PAPA
lion   ele     PAAA
mice   hello   PPAA
new    lion    PAPA
ele    that    PAAP
cat    lion    APAA
cub    pet     APPA
old    lion    APAA
new    lion    AAPA
hello  cat     AAPP
new    old     AAAP
```

The value should be at position 'i' is 'A' if they are not present in ith file, else it will 'P'. This is how the strings have been formed.

Comment: Please include the code you used in your attempts to solve this yourself.

Comment: @RichardScriven I have tried using merge function however i am not able to find out hoe to assign "A" or "P" and form a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small dataset, you can do this with reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

list_of_file_names = c(...)

data_frame(file = list_of_file_names) %>%
  group_by(file) %>%
  do(read.csv(.$file) ) %>%
  distinct %>%
  mutate(present = "P") %>%
  spread(file, present, fill = "A") %>%
  gather(file, present_absent, first_file_name:last_file_name) %>%
  group_by(column1, column2) %>%
  summarize(present_absent_string = 
              present_absent %>%
              paste(collapse = "") )
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am having troubles in installing tidyr package. Is  there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

> I am having troubles in installing tidyr package. Is there any other
>   way?

Here's one without an additional library.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla
# data input - filenames are to be provided as command line arguments:
t = lapply(commandArgs(T), read.table, col.names=1:2, flush=T)  # only 2 columns
t = mapply('[<-', t, 3, value="P", SIMPLIFY=F)  # mark the values as "present"
t = Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, 1:2, all=T, suffixes=ncol(x)), t) # merge
t[is.na(t)] = "A"           # mark the not present values as "absent"
t[3] = Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=''), t[-(1:2)])  # concatenate P&A
# data output - write the desired output format
write.table(format(t[1:3], justify="l"), quote=F, row.names=F, col.names=F)
```